# Where should I put code if I want it to run automatically?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I'm new to programming and I found an animation script that has code that is called in the `OnMouseDown` event, when the user clicks the object. I'd like the code to run automatically, instead of responding to an event. Where can I put code to be called automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure entirely what you mean by "code start automatically" or but I assume you want to make it so that the animations play immediately once the scene loads. If that is the case, all you need to do is call the "Play()" function inside the "Start()" function.

You should consider reading [Unity's Documentation on the Monobehaviour Class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html). What you have right now works because it is, essentially, overloading a function in the base Monobehaviour class which recieves an event on click. If you wish to define different conditions which make the animations play or stop, you need to add a function overload or implement your own logic depending on the results you desire.

Lastly, since you've added that you are new to programming, I would suggest you read up more on object oriented design and coding fundamentals before continuing with Unity. You can get by with looking at pre-made code samples, but understanding the way programming works on a fundamental level will help you when it comes to reading API documentation and understanding the flow of programming.

I hope this helps, let me know if you were looking for something more specific.

Comment: That did help me! I just didn't know where to put the "Play()" function exactly. Adding it inside the "Start()" function brought me just the result I wanted. Thanks!